# Mercurial: find all branches where commit exists

Tags: mercurial, branch

I have a few branches and a commit with ID X, I want Mercurial to return me a list of branches where that commit exists.

Mercurial already stores information about branch in every commit, but only about a branch in which that commit was introduced. If you merge that commit into some other branch, commit will still store only original branch name.

Comment: When you're talking branches and Mercurial it's worth mentioning what type of branch you mean.  Steve Losh's excellent "Guide to Branching in Mercurial" does a pretty good job of defining four of them: named branches (what you probably mean), bookmark branches (git style more or less), anonymous branches (forks in the DAG with the same names), and clones-as-branches (separate repos with separate lines of development all on the 'default' branch).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you could get what you want with this formula

```
hg log -r 'descendants(X) and head()'
```

`head()` includes all named branch heads, so even if the tip of a branch has been merged into another named branch, it will still be listed with this formula.

If you only want to show branch names, you will probably want to use the `--template '{branches}\n'` directive for the `hg log` command. If you have more than one head per named branch, you may end up using `uniq` or similar.

EDIT: To describe what this will do

```
A----B----C----D----E  Branch: default (E is a merge of F into D)
      \    \    \ /
       \    \    F     Branch B1 (closed)
        \    G-----H   Branch B2
         \    \
          \    I       Branch B2
           J           Branch B3
```

If you execute `hg log -r 'descendants(C) and head()'`, you should get E, F, H and I.

- **E**: You get E, because 'default' is a branch head, even though it has a special name.
- **F** comes up because even though you merged into E, it's still a `head()`, so it shows up on this list
- *G* is not a head, although it does contain C
- **H** is a head and clearly a descendant of C
- **I** branched from G, is also a head, and clearly contains C
- *J* is a head, but does not have C as an ancestor

Comment: Either there's a mistake or I don't get it. I created a new branch from default, added one commit to it then executed your command for that commit. It returned both the new branch and default, even though I never merged that branch into default. Shouldn't it return just the new branch?

Comment: Hmm... perhaps I misunderstood, breaking out a diagram.