# How to find all branches (or branch heads) not merged into another branch?

Tags: version-control, mercurial

How do I find all branch heads not merged into the `default` branch or any other branch?

```
1----2----4----6----8----13----14      Branch: default (E is a merge of F into D)
 \    \    \    \ /      /    
  \    \    \    7      /        Branch B1 (closed-merged)
   \    \    5-----9---+         Branch B2 (closed-merged)
    15   \    \                  Branch B5
          \    10          Branch B3
           3    \          Branch B4
            \    11        Branch B3
             12            Branch B4
```

In the above example (adapted from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7166185/268667)), I am trying to construct a search that will return changesets `11` ,`12` and `15` and the name of the branches (`Branch B3`,`Branch B4` and `Branch B5`) as branches not merged into `default`.

I would also expect a result of changesets `12`,`11`,`9`,`7` and `14` when compared to `Branch 5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using revsets you can accomplish it like this:

```
hg log -r 'not ancestors(14) and head()'
```

That should give you the changesets 11, 12, and 15. If you replaced 14 with 15, you should get the set you expect. To also exclude closed branches (7 and 9 in your example), you can add `and not closed()` to the revset definition:

```
hg log -r 'not ancestors(14) and head() and not closed()'
```

See more about [revsets](http://www.selenic.com/hg/help/revsets) on [hg's help pages](http://www.selenic.com/hg/help).

Answer (score 0):

95% of what you are asking for is provided with just:

```
hg heads
```

The only thing I can see wrong with it is that it does include the trunk tip, 14 in your example.